# Xcode doesn't display "Callers" in Assistant Editor when using conditional preprocessor directive

Tags: xcode

I recently ran into an issue where I would go to check the callers of a method using the Assistant Editor, but it would display as if there were no callers of the method in question.

I narrowed it down to that method being inside a conditional preprocessor directive. When I removed that, I was able to find the callers of the method.

Is there a way I can get Xcode to recognize the callers without removing the conditional preprocessor directives? Or do I need to continue with the work around every time?

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this issue but with a different cause. In my case, callers was greyed out because I had a device connected that was somehow preventing it working. Disconnecting the device caused the code coloring to work and populated the callers list

Edit: deleting device data under Window/Projects (Xcode 6.3.1) permitted code coloring to work again while the device was connected and callers list was again populated